# How to remove old domain that we don't have control over for branded searches that should only show our new site?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect, seo-audit

I changed my company website URL from www.tirnav.in to www.tirnav.com.
Google Webmaster had already indexed my earlier website i.e tirnav.in and now when i search google for Tirnav Solutions it still shows the pages URL from tirnav.in domain.

How can remove the tirnav.in from the Google Search Index since i do not own this URL now and dont have any control over it.

Please google for Tirnav Solutions and you will search results for both tirnav.in and tirnav.com

Comment: It is unfortunate that you don't have control over your old domain.  If you still had control, you could do a domain name move in Google Search Console.

Comment: If you don't have control over the old domain, you won't have much say over whether or not it is indexed.  The current owner could put up a site and could want it indexed and you shouldn't be able to tell Google not to index them.

Answer (score 1):

The domain `tirnav.in` doesn't appear to be currently registered or resolving. If you can re-purchase the domain and put 301 redirects in place to the new one, that would be ideal if you have backlinks that you want to keep.

Otherwise, **use the [Google Remove Outdated Content Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154?hl=en)** to speed up the old domain's removal from Google Search. This works because there is no website currently hosted at `tirnav.in`. If someone buys the domain and hosts content there, it might be more difficult to get it out of search results, especially if it already has backlinks.

Comment: Thanks Maximillan.
I have sent the request to remove the outdated URL from search result.

Comment: @Jayesh If you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to mark some answers as "helpful" using the arrows, and one of them as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't let go of your old domain if you can get it back do it ASAP.

When changing domain you should 301 redirect your old pages to the new ones and so they can pass the page rank.

I just searched for "Tirnav Solutions" and the .com version came up try cleaning your cache and try incognito mode.

Comment: It isn't just a cache / localisation issue. I see both the `.in` and `.com` domains in the SERPs (try a `site:` search on the `.in` domain).

Comment: Yes .in comes up on the search as well but is just matter of time until google removes it since is a inactive domain.